# Android studio and Object libraries

Tags: c++, android-studio, cmake

In my Android Studio Gradle project I have some C++ code, that is a part of my own CMake OBJECT library. This library is later used for JNI. The project compiles and runs fine, but Android Studio does not index files in the Object library. It thinks that these files are not a part of the project.

What can I do to force Android Studio to index files in my object library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple workaround: Create a new SHARED library target that contains files from the OBJECT library. This library does not get compiled, however the code now belongs to a target that Android Studio can see, so it indexes them.